# How to execute an Installshield Custom action while Rollback?

Tags: installshield, custom-action, conditional-statements, rollback

I have an InstallShield installer which does some stuff. In case the installation breaks the rollback sequence gets started. I do know that I can create conditions for my custom actions in order to make it run only during install or uninstall, but which condition do I set to make it run on rollback?

To be precisely I need rollback and remove. At the moment I have already set REMOVE which works perfectly on uninstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rollback is not detected through conditions. Instead set the in-script execution of the custom action to one of the rollback options. This action will then run only during a rollback that occurs after the sequence at which it was scheduled, and only if its condition was true at that point in the sequence.